# Multiple dateInput formats on mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2, formatdatetime

I'm creating two mat-datepickers, one with the format "MM/YYYY" and another with the format "DD/MM/YYYY",but i can't configure both formats in the module.

I tried to put in one module the settings for MM/YYYY and in the app module the settings for DD/MM/YYYY.

Code 1:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
...

providers: [{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
  {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS}]
};
```

Code 2:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
...
providers: [{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS}]
})
```

If i use the DD/MM/YYYY format in the settings,all dates show as DD/MM/YYYY,if i don't use,all dates show as MM/YYYY. What should i do to show one date as MM/YYYY and another as DD/MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this doing exactly like the examples of Datepicker in Angular Material Wiki,instead of defining the DateAdapter and Date Formats providers in the Module, i defined it in the Component,then it worked.

Comment: if you want set different date formats for each input controls just use below code.you can set any date format for input control what date format you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field><input
    type="text"
    [value]="VisitorsCurrentDate"
    class="visit_date"
    (click)="patientVisitPicker.open()"
    style="text-transform: capitalize"
    style="border: none" /><input
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="patientVisitPicker"
    (dateInput)="setPatientsVisitsDateTiming($event.value)"
    style="display: none"
    class="mat_class" /><mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="patientVisitPicker"
    style="display: none"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle
  ><mat-datepicker
    [dateClass]="dateClass"
    #patientVisitPicker
    style="display: none"
  ></mat-datepicker
></mat-form-field>

public setPatientsVisitsDateTiming(date:any){
    this.VisitorsCurrentDate = moment(date, "D-M-YYYY").format("DD MMM YYYY");
}
```

Comment: if you want set different date formats for each input controls just use above code.you can set any date format for input control what date format you want. try this way....